# Double border/frame in some holo components

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I have a problem settings the holo style using holoeverywhere.Using some of the components I can see a double frame that look horrible. I've tried different settings but I can not find the solution. I think I am using badly this library.

I am going to attach some image to be clear:

[image]

I am going to describe a bit how I am working with them:

In my manifest, I am not ussing any style from this library. Actually I am using this style:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

For the progress bar I am not ussing any xml, only a object

```
private ProgressDialog mPD;
```

which is imported from

```
import org.holoeverywhere.app.ProgressDialog;
```

and I call it using:

```
mPD =  ProgressDialog.show(context, null, progressMessage, true, true);
```

That's all.

For the TimePicker, I am creating this in runtime creating this object

```
new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_NoActionBar, timePickerListener,calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();
```

I have no idea about what I am doing bad...how I could delete this frame under my holo objects. Any subjections? Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at my answer. It may help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If. You. Not use. Styles from library... For what are you use library?
it's most stupid and horrible use-case for library. Really.
Not mix native/compat styles with compat/native classes. Never.

Comment: Yep, I didn't realize of this small but important detail. I set the style of my activity as a holoeverywhere one. It fixed my problem. Thanks but you should take care of your manners. we are here to learn and to be helpful for everybody. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with time picker dialogs... Class `TimePickerDialog` inherits its own theme constants from `AlertDialog`. Same goes for other dialogs we've got from `AlertDialog`. You must use those in order to get predictable results. Try this code:

```
new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, timePickerListener, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();
```

Or maybe use `TimePickerDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT`, if you prefer to stay with what user expects. Since images show dark theme, maybe you'd like that... Well, documentation says you may use the following constants:

- `TimePickerDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK`
- `TimePickerDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT`
- `TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK`
- `TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT`
- `TimePickerDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL`